# How to handle communication errors properly? QT SerialPort

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port

I have a bidirectional communication through the serial port.

```
MyClass::MyClass(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    //setUp 

    connect(serial, SIGNAL(error(QSerialPort::SerialPortError)), this,
           SLOT(handleError(QSerialPort::SerialPortError)));
}

void MyClass::handleError(QSerialPort::SerialPortError error)
{ 
  //show error
  //close connection
}

void MyClass::send(QString data)
{
    if(!data.endsWith('\r'))
        data.append('\r');

    //should be like this:
    serial->write(data.toLocal8Bit()); 
    serial->waitForBytesWritten(TIMEOUT);


    //or this?
    if( serial->write(data.toLocal8Bit()) < 0 )
        emit serial->error(QSerialPort::WriteError);    

    if(!serial->waitForBytesWritten(TIMEOUT))
        emit serial->error(QSerialPort::TimeoutError);

}

void MyClass::receive(char &dest, int size)
{
    //similar to send
}
```

Namely, **handleError** will automatically handle the Serial Port Errors or should I detect & throw them?

Which of the 2 ways is more correct? Or none of them is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
if (serial->write(data.toLocal8Bit()) < 0 )
    emit serial->error(QSerialPort::WriteError);
```

is wrong, since the `QSerialPort` class already emits the signal, why do you want to do it yourself?

You should both handle the `error` signal that the `QSerialPort` emits, and handle any immediate errors returned by the `write`, `read` and other methods. You need to handle the signal because the reading and writing happens asynchronously. A write that "succeeds" and returns the number of bytes you intended, does simply mean that the device was open and was in a "usable" state at the moment. The actual write happens in the background and may fail at any time.

The simple, and correct thing to do, is to have a state machine that implements the communications protocol you're after. The state machine framework is there to help you.